# k3s: The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

When I run any `kubectl` commands, I'm getting

> The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem is likely caused by a bad `~/.kube/config` perhaps you have a file from a different kubernetes install (minikube) or an older k3s. If the server is local you can fix this by running  these commands,

```
mkdir ~/.kube
sudo k3s kubectl config view --raw | tee ~/.kube/config
chmod 600 ~/.kube/config
```

The contents of `~/.kube/config` need to have the same information as `/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml` when the server was started (the keys, ip, and ports).

---

Note in order to tell k3s to use this config file [you'll want to configure `KUBECONFIG`](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/16044/18965).

```
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config
```

You should persist this by having it set in `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`