# error: error loading config file "/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml": open /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml: permission denied

Tags: rancher, k3s

When I run commands under `k3s kubectl`, I get

```shell
$ k3s kubectl version
WARN[0000] Unable to read /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml, please start server with --write-kubeconfig-mode to modify kube config permissions 
error: error loading config file "/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml" : open /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml: permission denied
```

How should I resolve this? Should I change the permissions of `/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## No, do not change permissions of `/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml`

First set up your an environmental variable for `KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config`.

```
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config
```

Then let's generate the file at that location. [Your `k3s.yaml` file should **NOT** be world readable.](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/389). This is by-design. It should be owned by root and set to `0600`. Instead copy the config locally as [described here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/16014/18965),

```shell
mkdir ~/.kube 2> /dev/null
sudo k3s kubectl config view --raw > "$KUBECONFIG"
chmod 600 "$KUBECONFIG"
```

You can add `KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config` to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` to make it persist on reboot.

Comment: If the "sudo k3s kubectl ..." line is giving an error stating "sudo: k3s: command not found", then you can try by adding ```/usr/local/bin/``` in front of "k3s". Which would make that line as this: ```sudo /usr/local/bin/k3s kubectl config view --raw > "$KUBECONFIG"```

Comment: @UNOPARATOR the only way that could make a difference is if `/usr/local/bin` is not in your `$PATH` which would be pretty awkward anyway.

Comment: In my case with a CentOS 8 Stream server, after the k3s installation that line wasn't working. There was no mention of adding that to ```$PATH``` but it might be considered common practice and not mentioned because of that. I'm no linux expert of any kind, just commented in case someone like me encounters the same issue.

Comment: When you run `echo $PATH` you should see `/usr/local/bin` in your path. Almost certainly CentOS does that. (also, CentOS is dead, everyone went to Rocky).

Comment: It wasn't there, so added ```export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin``` line to ```$HOME/.bashrc```. (Just checked out Rocky Linux from wiki, might try that next time - thanks for the heads up)

Comment: @UNOPARATOR, the problem is that on CentOS by default `sudo` will use a PATH value different from your own PATH. This other value does not include `/usr/local/bin`, which is why it couldn't find the `k3s` command. One way to resolve this is to add `/usr/local/bin` to the `secure_path` option in `/etc/sudoers`. See https://superuser.com/questions/927512/how-to-set-path-for-sudo-commands for details. Ubuntu and Debian do not have this issue (`secure_path` includes `/usr/local/bin`).