# With kubectl, I'm getting Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubectl, k3s

When I run something with k3s, like `kubectl apply`, I'm getting

> Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably means you've got a dangling `~/.kube/config` left over from a prior installation where you [followed instructions like these to set up `~/.kube/config`](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/16044/18965) and you've since reinstalled k3s and left the old kubeconfig. You simply need to generate a new copy of your `~/.kube/config` in your home directory.

You can do this like this,

```
# if not set, set it to the right location
# export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config

sudo k3s kubectl config view --raw > "$KUBECONFIG"
```